# JAVA - Modify Employee

Tags: java

Be kind, learning.

These are the classes I have:  Employee, salaryworker, hourlyworker, PayrollTest

I need to be able to modify existing employee, but I need it to be able to tell the difference if its an hourly or salary worker as they have different inputs. I can find the employee by its id, but not how to modify it correctly.  I'm lost on how to do this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class PayrollTest {

    //Array Lists for Hourly and Salary Workers.
    public static hourlyworker hourlyEmp = new hourlyworker(null, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static ArrayList<hourlyworker> hourlyList = new ArrayList<hourlyworker>();
    //(String name, int dependents, double annualSalary, int month, int day, int year) {

    public static salaryworker salaryEmp = new salaryworker(null, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static ArrayList<salaryworker> salaryList = new ArrayList<salaryworker>();

    //Arraylist Initializing
    public static ArrayList emps = new ArrayList();  //<Employee>

    //Initializing scanner for user input
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Fields needed for PayrollTest
    private static char choice;
    private static char typeChoice;
    private static boolean switcher = true;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        menuSelection();
        System.out.println();


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void loadHourlyEmployee() {

        System.out.println("\nEnter full name, number of dependents, hourly rate, regular hours worked, overtime worked, and date hired (yyyy mm dd)");
        System.out.println("[one field per line, except date hired]: ");
        hourlyEmp = new hourlyworker(null, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0);

        hourlyEmp.setName(scan.nextLine());
        hourlyEmp.setDependents(scan.nextInt());
        hourlyEmp.setPayrate(scan.nextDouble());
        hourlyEmp.setHours(scan.nextDouble());
        hourlyEmp.setOvertimeHours(scan.nextDouble());
        hourlyEmp.setHireDay(scan.nextInt());
        emps.add(hourlyEmp);

        System.out.println("\nYou entered an employee type for non-exempt: hourly.");


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void loadSalaryEmployee() {

        System.out.println("\nEnter full name, number of dependents, annual salary, and date hired (yyyy mm dd)");
        System.out.println("[one field per line, except date hired]: ");
        salaryEmp = new salaryworker(null, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0);

        salaryEmp.setName(scan.nextLine());
        salaryEmp.setDependents(scan.nextInt());
        salaryEmp.setAnnualSalary(scan.nextDouble());
        salaryEmp.setHireDay(scan.nextInt());
        emps.add(salaryEmp);

        System.out.println("\nYou entered an employee type for exempt: salary.");


    }

    private static void menuSelection() {
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n\tEmployee Database");
            System.out.println("\nEmployee Info Menu");
            System.out.println("\tEnter L to (L)oad Employee info");
            System.out.println("\tEnter M to (M)odify Employee info");
            System.out.println("\tEnter P to (P)rint Employee info");
            System.out.println("\tEnter Q to quit");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
            choice = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

            //Choice validation
            while ((choice != 'L') && (choice != 'M') && (choice != 'P')  && (choice != 'Q')) {

                System.out.println("Invalid choice!  Please select (L)oad, (M)odify, (P)rint, or (Q)uit: ");
                choice = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            }



            //Switch Statement
            switch (choice) {
            case 'L' : 

                System.out.println("What is the employee type? S = salary H = hourly ");
                System.out.print("\n[Please enter letter] : ");
                typeChoice = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

                //typeChoice validation
                while ((typeChoice != 'S') && (typeChoice != 'H')) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice!  Please select (S)alary, (H)ourly: ");
                    typeChoice = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                }   

                if (typeChoice == 'H') {
                    loadHourlyEmployee();}

                else if (typeChoice == 'S') {
                    loadSalaryEmployee();
                }

                break;

            case 'M' : 

                modifyEmployee();


                break;

            case 'P' : 
                printEmployees();
                break;

            case 'Q' : 
                switcher = false;
                System.out.println("\nProgram Terminated.");
                break;

            }
        }

        while (switcher != false);


    }



    private static void printEmployees() {
        System.out.println("\nThere are " + emps.size() + " people in this database.\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < emps.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(emps.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("\nTotal = " + emps.size());
    }
    private static void modifyEmployee() {

        System.out.print("Employee id#? ");
        int findID = scan.nextInt();

        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;
        boolean deleteMod = false;
        int index1 = 0;

        while (index < emps.size() && !found) {
            if (emps.get(index) != null) {
                found = true;
            }

            deleteMod = true;

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Info: ");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you really expect us to read this much code? please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also tell us were you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `instanceof` to determine if it is the class you want or not.

```
if (emps.get(index) instanceof hourlyworker) {
  // code for hourlyworker
} else {
  // code for salaryworker
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` operator in java will help you here. As you are in learning mode, I will prefer you find out about it, rather than me explaining here.